# Can SharePoint index WordPerfect documents?

Tags: sharepoint-online

Can SharePoint online index WordPerfect documents?

Comment: Hi Miadatlantic this might help you http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1540997

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint Online does not support the WordPefrect Indexing. As per the technet article, Wordperfect is not list supported file type.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219530.aspx

But if you have on prem then you can install the Ifilter for Wordperfect.